# C# Listview avoid default row selection

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, selection, default

I have Listview with Checkboxes enable and whenever it gets loaded the very first row gets selected by default. And I'm not setting it in the code.

So how can I avoid this default selection of the first row?

Comment: when/if you accept this duplicate, I will delete my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the [SelectedIndex](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listview.selectedindex(v=vs.110).aspx) to -1 when you load your form

```
listView1.SelectedIndex = -1;
```

Answer (score 0):

try with

```
myListView.SelectedItems.Clear();
```